# Prime numbers for a given range

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, a, b, c=0;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    for(i=a; i<=b; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        if(c==2)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program however does not print prime numbers for a given range. Please help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: the `if(c==2)` part should be in the for loop as else part of `j==0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset `c` to `0` after every iteration. The loops should look like this

```
for(i=a; i<=b; i++)
{
    c = 0;
    ...
```

> An advice, you don't have to go till the number everytime to check for primality, you can go till square root of that number.

Comment: If it's optimal to arrange this in such a way, you only need to iterate over the *primes* up to the square root. Of course, you'd need to change your reliance on `c` if you do that.